# Method does not return anything at all

Tags: java, arrays, methods, error-handling, delimiter

I wrote a method which gets as an input an array of numbers and an integer (which will be the delimiter) the method will return a 2D array that is sliced according to the delimiter not including the delimiter. 
Examples:

```
splitArrayNyNum([0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1], 3) -> [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]

splitArrayNyNum([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1], 3) -> [[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 1, 2, 2], [1]]

splitArrayNyNum([3 , 1 ,3 ,3], 3) -> [[1]]
```

For some reason when I move my mouse over the name of the method I get the error that my function should return `int[][]`

This is my code:

```
public static int[][] splitArrayByNum(int[] input, int number){
        if (input[0]==number)
               for ( int i = 0 ; i < input.length - 1 ; i++ )
               {
                  input[ i ] = input[ i + 1 ] ; 
               }

        if ((input[(input.length)-1])==number)
               for ( int i = (input.length)-1 ; i < input.length - 1 ; i++ )
               {
                  input[ i ] = input[ i + 1 ] ; 
               }

                  int count = 0;
                  for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                    if (input[i] == number) {
                      count++;
                    }


        int[][] result = new int[count][];
        int firstindex=0;
        int lastindex=0;


        for (int j=0; j<input.length; j++){

            if (input[j]==number){
                result[j]=Arrays.copyOfRange(input, firstindex, lastindex);
                firstindex=lastindex=j; 

            }
         lastindex++ ; 

        }


        return result ;
}
```

Comment: You also get another compiler warning: "Dead code" for the `i++` in the last for loop using the variable `i`: `for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)`. This warning could direct you to the problem: The loop is executed only once. The increment never happens. Why? Because you are _returning_ from inside that loop. Did you want that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `result` is defined in the for-loop scope.

Please, format your code, and you will see that `result` isn't "visible" from return statement.

***UPDATE:*** Friendly remainder: you can format selected code in ***eclipse*** with a shortkey: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

**Formatted code:**

```
public static int[][] splitArrayByNum(int[] input, int number){
  if (input[0]==number)
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < input.length - 1 ; i++ )
    {
      input[ i ] = input[ i + 1 ] ; 
    }

  if ((input[(input.length)-1])==number)
    for ( int i = (input.length)-1 ; i < input.length - 1 ; i++ )
    {
      input[ i ] = input[ i + 1 ] ; 
    }

  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i] == number) {
      count++;
    }

    int[][] result = new int[count][];
    int firstindex=0;
    int lastindex=0;

    for (int j=0; j<input.length; j++){

      if (input[j]==number){
        result[j]=Arrays.copyOfRange(input, firstindex, lastindex);
        firstindex=lastindex=j; 
      }
      lastindex++ ; 
    }
    return result ;
  }
```

You may see that you don't have the method closing `}`, and the result is defined in the `for-loop` scope, and is returned from there, but I believe that you want to return the `result` ***after*** the *for-loop*, isn't it?

I suppose that your code should look like this:

```
public static int[][] splitArrayByNum(int[] input, int number){
  if (input[0]==number)
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < input.length - 1 ; i++ )
    {
      input[ i ] = input[ i + 1 ] ; 
    }

  if ((input[(input.length)-1])==number)
    for ( int i = (input.length)-1 ; i < input.length - 1 ; i++ )
    {
      input[ i ] = input[ i + 1 ] ; 
    }

  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) /*removed bracket here*/
    if (input[i] == number) {
      count++;
    }

  int[][] result = new int[count][];
  int firstindex=0;
  int lastindex=0;

  for (int j=0; j<input.length; j++){

    if (input[j]==number){
      result[j]=Arrays.copyOfRange(input, firstindex, lastindex);
      firstindex=lastindex=j; 
    }
    lastindex++ ; 
  }
  return result ;
}
```

also, I guess that you have a mistake in the line `result[j]=Arrays.copyOfRange(input, firstindex, lastindex);`. It's possible that `j` will be larger that `count` (the size of the `result`). So, you should have another counter or pointer to the last free element in the `result` array (destination to copy the next chunk of array).

**UPDATE 3:**

Well, I don't know how much fair it is, but I did all *YOUR* work by myself.
Here is the code, which actually works (with comments):

```
public static int[][] splitArrayByNum(int[] input, int number) {
    if(input.length == 0) {
        return new int[0][];
    }

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i] == number) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    if(input[input.length - 1] != number) {
        /*we need to add the end of the array manually*/
        count ++;
    }

    int[][] result = new int[count][];
    int firstIndex = 0;

    int iter = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
        if (input[j] == number) {
            result[iter++] = Arrays.copyOfRange(input, firstIndex, j);
            firstIndex = j+1;
        }
    }
    if(input[input.length - 1] != number) {
        /*manually adding the end of the array*/
        result[count-1] = Arrays.copyOfRange(input, firstIndex, input.length);
    }

    return result;
}
```

I run it using the next few lines, and that works just like expected:

```
int[] inp = new int[]{1, 3, 3, 5};
int[][] sp = splitArrayByNum(inp, 3);
for(int i=0;i<sp.length;i++) {
    System.out.print(i + ": ");
    for(int j=0;j<sp[i].length;j++) {
        System.out.print(sp[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Also, at some point, you may have empty parts (after the split). So, I leave it up to you to clean it up (they may appear everywhere(not only at the beginning or the end), if there are two consecutive split-numbers in the `input` array).

Comment: Yes, I need to return the result after the loop, I tried adding a closing }, but then I got an error that result is not defined!

Comment: @user3369309 so, you should move `result` declaration above the for loop and than the `return` after the for-loop. Maybe, you just didn't copy that closing curly bracket at the end and the bracket sequence is correct.

Comment: @user3369309 I have updated the answer. Please, take a look and let me know if you still have any questions.

Comment: The updated answer looks good but it's still doesn't return anything. Do you think there is something wrong in it?

Comment: @user3369309 see updated answer with fully working code.